# Converting 64-bit bmp file to array in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, image, bmp

Well, I'm a newbie in C++, and it's been two days since I'm looking for examples, explanations, I try different libraries, but I can not do it, so I just ask for help.

I have a picture in .bmp, I know the height and length, I would like to use in my program as a 2D array.

So I found [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14610817/2772576), but it does not work. The problem is that my image is 64 bpp, although visually monochrome.

I have read [the documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format), but I do not understand, due to my poor skills in C++ and everything related to the low-level programming.

Do you think it is possible to adapt the previous code for bmp image of 64 bits per pixel?

Comment: modify fread()...and for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge the bitmap file format does not support 64 bits per component.  I'm not aware of any file format that allows such a format (Though id be surprised if one did not exist).

I find it hard to understand why you would need such a VAST range for an image format component.

***Edit***: Given your comment then yes it is absoloutely possible to adapt that code.  Though its worth noting that 0..63 (64 colour levels) is 6-bit.  I assume 2 bits are wasted, though.

Its quite simple if it is grayscale and the component is 8bpp.  Basically the storage you need is width * height bytes.

```
char* pBitmap = malloc( bmp.width * bmp.height );
```

You can then fread the pixels directly into the char buffer above with a single width * height read.

***Edit 2***:

Ok for 16 bit per component with 4 components you need a struct like this:

```
struct Pixel16RGBA
{
    unsigned short r;
    unsigned short g;
    unsigned short b;
    unsigned short a;
};
```

and then you'd allocate as follows:

```
Pixel16RGBA* pBitmap = (Pixel16RGBA)malloc( bmp.width * bmp.height * 4 * sizeof( unsigned short ) );
```

You would then fread the whole image in, as before, using the size calcluated in the malloc above.

Comment: You point the finger at something that I must have misunderstood.

Because I think I was mistaken. My image has a color depth of 64, that means she is 64/8 = 8 bits per pixel, 8 bpp and not 64 as I said, is not it?

Comment: In fact, the color depth IS the number of bits per pixel. It is therefore a 64 bpp image that I try to open. According to research, there are four channels of 65,536 shades of color. But the documentation on this subject is not abundant.

Comment: @user2772576: 65536 shades is 2^16 and hence 16-bit per channel ... so yes its a 64bpp image but its 16-bit per pixel.  As its grayscale, though, you could easily store it as 1 16-bit channel.

Comment: oops I mean 16-bit per component not pixel

Comment: Based on Jason Summers bmpsuite 2.7 test images, the 64bpp bitmap is *BGRA* order like standard 8-bit per channel BGRA DIBs. Each channel ranges 0 to 0x2000 (rather than 0xFFFF), and so to convert to 8-bit BGRA, use x * 255 / 8192. Otherwise the colors are way too dark.